# Use browser same page jump link functionality with offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, scroll

I want to use the same browser URL hash functionality but with offset based on the height of the sticky header. Currently, content goes behind header.

Here is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmyafjt7/13/

The Javascript solution I tried but not working:

```
const targetJumplinkWrapName = e.target.getAttribute("href").split("#")[1]; // returns destination element id name
const element = document.getElementById(targetJumplinkWrapName);
const elementTop = element.offsetTop + window.innerHeight - 250;
window.scrollTo({ top: elementTop, behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the brute-force solution is adding a "scroll-margin-top" to the "jumplink-wrap" class such as:

```
.jumplink-wrap{scroll-margin-top:60px;}
```

where 60px is the header height in the jsfiddle given.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `:target` pseudo element

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background: green
}

.nav {
  padding-top: 70px
}

.jumplink-wrap:target::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;

  /* Your header height */
  height: 60px;
  margin: -60px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>

<nav class="nav" id="jumpNav">
  <ul>
    <li class="" data-id="introduction"><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li data-id="aut_ducimus" class="active"><a href="#aut_ducimus">Aut ducimus</a></li>
    <li data-id="sit_inventore_debitis" class=""><a href="#sit_inventore_debitis">Sit inventore debitis</a></li>
    <li data-id="et_corrupti" class=""><a href="#et_corrupti">Et corrupti</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="article-content">
  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="introduction"></div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>



  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>



  <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>


  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="aut_ducimus">
    <h2>Aut ducimus</h2>
  </div>



  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In sint quos vel cupiditate nemo At unde quasi. Non minima molestiae sit dolorem nostrum eum odit nihil vel nobis tempore sit voluptatibus dolorem. Non accusantium voluptate qui error iste ut pariatur repudiandae At molestias obcaecati aut ipsa debitis. Sit ipsam dicta est ipsa iste et minus voluptatibus et autem saepe et repudiandae nostrum.</p>



  <p>A porro quibusdam ut eaque blanditiis et esse voluptates. Sed harum vitae et quia iste id laudantium minus et possimus dolorum ut officia neque eos recusandae atque est perferendis expedita? Eum nesciunt omnis id voluptatem excepturi qui quasi libero eos eligendi omnis et numquam aperiam ut illum inventore est debitis voluptas. Et sint quia aut esse temporibus hic voluptas dolores est voluptatem delectus At omnis fugiat eum nihil doloribus.</p>



  <p>Sit quis distinctio ut rerum libero et asperiores repellendus vel accusantium voluptatibus quo culpa magnam eum voluptatem nihil est possimus iusto. Et natus quos eum molestiae officiis non minus dolorem est sint ducimus. Eum mollitia dolorem ut deserunt natus ea unde nihil.</p>


  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="sit_inventore_debitis">
    <h2>Sit inventore debitis</h2>
  </div>



  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et voluptatem nobis vel deleniti distinctio et placeat consequuntur qui aliquid quisquam ex quia vitae. Sed cumque nostrum in velit necessitatibus vel quia quod ut magni optio est quam aperiam non omnis illum.</p>



  <p>Id illum vitae a facere soluta ut fugiat nostrum. Non sunt dolor ut soluta nihil est placeat repellendus ab amet animi sit dolorem temporibus! Est voluptatem itaque eos eveniet deleniti qui voluptas facilis et voluptatem doloremque et magnam amet est sequi quod.</p>


  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="et_corrupti">
    <h2>Et corrupti</h2>
  </div>



  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id nihil repellendus sit dolor excepturi quo aspernatur voluptates eum repellat voluptate. Est obcaecati veritatis ut explicabo veritatis ut delectus quia ad accusamus dolore ut optio consequatur et rerum tenetur qui quibusdam eligendi.</p>



  <p>Rem recusandae aliquid est deserunt Quis aut unde nihil ea aliquam quisquam vel tempora quibusdam et autem nemo. At magnam consequatur et reiciendis eligendi sit exercitationem voluptate ut dolorem harum est doloremque repellendus cum beatae rerum. Et provident sint sed beatae molestiae eos quas distinctio. Est voluptates commodi vel voluptatibus praesentium est sint saepe id quae amet et illum quam qui cupiditate voluptatibus.</p>



  <p>Aut numquam officia et doloremque praesentium et dolorum molestiae in illo nulla sed quos reprehenderit est fuga dolorem sed quaerat blanditiis. Et voluptates consequatur sed cumque deserunt vel asperiores nulla est ducimus tempora id quia sapiente ex repudiandae voluptatem 33 quaerat molestias.</p>



  <p>Non ipsam reiciendis non nulla aliquam est voluptate veniam qui dolor blanditiis? Ea internos distinctio vel eligendi veniam sit assumenda nesciunt eum eius quos cum aperiam autem eum quibusdam eius.</p>



  <p>In fuga quia a praesentium accusamus sit dolores consectetur. Est nobis nostrum ut vitae labore aut odio voluptatibus sit laboriosam expedita aut voluptas voluptatibus aut quia saepe ut recusandae unde.</p>



  <p>Vel soluta rerum At rerum maxime aut aperiam neque aut enim voluptatibus qui laborum delectus ea sunt repellendus. Et quia voluptatibus eum reprehenderit molestias vel amet sunt. Et quisquam ullam eum illum nisi in aliquid recusandae et quam corrupti. Aut architecto dolor sit iure consequatur in nihil saepe ut consequatur consequatur.</p>
```

Comment: I have a sticky header, the above solution works on desktop but fails on mobile, actually I have a jump to dropdown which sticks to top on scroll. And on click of dropdown, it should scroll to particular element with offset. Consider it as a blog page

Comment: I don't understand can you add your all html/css structure as a snippet to the question so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

working perfectly, write a script for you. please have a look

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#jumpNav a')
for (const element of links) {
    element.addEventListener('click', smoothScroll);
}
function smoothScroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const hash = e.target.hash;
    const headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;;
    const elementOffset = document.querySelector(`${hash}`).offsetTop;
    const hashOffsetTop = (elementOffset - headerHeight);

    window.scrollTo({ top: hashOffsetTop, behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

```css
* {
            margin: 0
        }

        header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            color: #fff;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            background: green
        }

        .nav {
            padding-top: 70px
        }
```

```html
<header>HEADER</header>

    <nav class="nav" id="jumpNav">
        <ul>
            <li class="" data-id="introduction"><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
            <li data-id="aut_ducimus" class="active"><a href="#aut_ducimus">Aut ducimus</a></li>
            <li data-id="sit_inventore_debitis" class=""><a href="#sit_inventore_debitis">Sit inventore debitis</a></li>
            <li data-id="et_corrupti" class=""><a href="#et_corrupti">Et corrupti</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="article-content">
        <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="introduction"></div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>


        <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="aut_ducimus">
            <h2>Aut ducimus</h2>
        </div>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In sint quos vel cupiditate nemo At unde quasi. Non minima molestiae sit dolorem
            nostrum eum odit nihil vel nobis tempore sit voluptatibus dolorem. Non accusantium voluptate qui error iste
            ut pariatur repudiandae At molestias obcaecati aut ipsa debitis. Sit ipsam dicta est ipsa iste et minus
            voluptatibus et autem saepe et repudiandae nostrum.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>



        <p>A porro quibusdam ut eaque blanditiis et esse voluptates. Sed harum vitae et quia iste id laudantium minus et
            possimus dolorum ut officia neque eos recusandae atque est perferendis expedita? Eum nesciunt omnis id
            voluptatem excepturi qui quasi libero eos eligendi omnis et numquam aperiam ut illum inventore est debitis
            voluptas. Et sint quia aut esse temporibus hic voluptas dolores est voluptatem delectus At omnis fugiat eum
            nihil doloribus.</p>



        <p>Sit quis distinctio ut rerum libero et asperiores repellendus vel accusantium voluptatibus quo culpa magnam
            eum voluptatem nihil est possimus iusto. Et natus quos eum molestiae officiis non minus dolorem est sint
            ducimus. Eum mollitia dolorem ut deserunt natus ea unde nihil.</p>


        <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="sit_inventore_debitis">
            <h2>Sit inventore debitis</h2>
        </div>



        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et voluptatem nobis vel deleniti distinctio et placeat consequuntur qui aliquid
            quisquam ex quia vitae. Sed cumque nostrum in velit necessitatibus vel quia quod ut magni optio est quam
            aperiam non omnis illum.</p>



        <p>Id illum vitae a facere soluta ut fugiat nostrum. Non sunt dolor ut soluta nihil est placeat repellendus ab
            amet animi sit dolorem temporibus! Est voluptatem itaque eos eveniet deleniti qui voluptas facilis et
            voluptatem doloremque et magnam amet est sequi quod.</p>


        <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="et_corrupti">
            <h2>Et corrupti</h2>
        </div>


        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id nihil repellendus sit dolor excepturi quo aspernatur voluptates eum repellat
            voluptate. Est obcaecati veritatis ut explicabo veritatis ut delectus quia ad accusamus dolore ut optio
            consequatur et rerum tenetur qui quibusdam eligendi.</p>



        <p>Rem recusandae aliquid est deserunt Quis aut unde nihil ea aliquam quisquam vel tempora quibusdam et autem
            nemo. At magnam consequatur et reiciendis eligendi sit exercitationem voluptate ut dolorem harum est
            doloremque repellendus cum beatae rerum. Et provident sint sed beatae molestiae eos quas distinctio. Est
            voluptates commodi vel voluptatibus praesentium est sint saepe id quae amet et illum quam qui cupiditate
            voluptatibus.</p>



        <p>Aut numquam officia et doloremque praesentium et dolorum molestiae in illo nulla sed quos reprehenderit est
            fuga dolorem sed quaerat blanditiis. Et voluptates consequatur sed cumque deserunt vel asperiores nulla est
            ducimus tempora id quia sapiente ex repudiandae voluptatem 33 quaerat molestias.</p>



        <p>Non ipsam reiciendis non nulla aliquam est voluptate veniam qui dolor blanditiis? Ea internos distinctio vel
            eligendi veniam sit assumenda nesciunt eum eius quos cum aperiam autem eum quibusdam eius.</p>



        <p>In fuga quia a praesentium accusamus sit dolores consectetur. Est nobis nostrum ut vitae labore aut odio
            voluptatibus sit laboriosam expedita aut voluptas voluptatibus aut quia saepe ut recusandae unde.</p>



        <p>Vel soluta rerum At rerum maxime aut aperiam neque aut enim voluptatibus qui laborum delectus ea sunt
            repellendus. Et quia voluptatibus eum reprehenderit molestias vel amet sunt. Et quisquam ullam eum illum
            nisi in aliquid recusandae et quam corrupti. Aut architecto dolor sit iure consequatur in nihil saepe ut
            consequatur consequatur.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus
            obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita
            ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut
            laudantium Quis.</p>
        <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet
            aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum
            explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam
            et alias laudantium.</p>
        <p>Non corporis voluptatibus et numquam aspernatur qui repellat quae qui sequi voluptatem. At magni sequi ut
            expedita odit et officia doloribus ut repudiandae accusantium sed ipsa quam 33 doloribus unde!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make your header `position: sticky` - therefore there's no need to set margin-top to anything
- Use `scroll-margin-top` like: `.jumplink-wrap {scroll-margin-top: var(--header-height); }`
- to smooth scroll use: `scroll-behavior: smooth;` on the `html`

Example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --header-height: 60px; 
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.article-content {
  max-width: 40rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

header {
  /* INSTEAD OF fixed */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  background: hsla(127, 80%, 50%, 0.8);
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

header nav a {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.jumplink-wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: var(--header-height);
}

.nav {
  /*padding-top: 70px; /* NOT NEEDED */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="nav" id="jumpNav">
    <a href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#aut_ducimus">Aut ducimus</a>
    <a href="#sit_inventore_debitis">Sit inventore debitis</a>
    <a href="#et_corrupti">Et corrupti</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="article-content">
  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="introduction">
    <h2>Introduction</h2>
  </div>

  <p>ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit velit
    quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>

  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa
    pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>


  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="aut_ducimus">
    <h2>Aut ducimus</h2>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit
    velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>

  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa
    pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>

  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="sit_inventore_debitis">
    <h2>Sit inventore debitis</h2>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit
    velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>

  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa
    pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>

  <div class="jumplink-wrap" id="et_corrupti">
    <h2>Et corrupti</h2>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit
    velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>

  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa
    pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>
  ž
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Id dicta consequatur qui ipsum cupiditate qui numquam doloribus et possimus obcaecati hic maiores natus ex molestiae labore est repudiandae totam? Aut quasi itaque qui earum expedita ab quos adipisci qui dolores enim sit
    velit quibusdam. Ex molestiae recusandae et distinctio blanditiis aut laudantium Quis.</p>

  <p>Vel facere iure aut voluptatum adipisci sit rerum repudiandae qui vitae nihil rem numquam nulla cum eveniet aperiam et voluptate culpa. Eum voluptate voluptates qui ipsam eius ut nobis facere id quia porro eum explicabo pariatur in nobis sint. Sit culpa
    pariatur ut aliquid aliquid ut maiores ipsum est pariatur totam et alias laudantium.</p>

</div>
```